# Divs using inline-block are overlapping when parent element is resized

Tags: html, css

On my webpage there are [Gridster](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/) widgets which have multiple images in them.Images can be added with `+` button.The widgets can be resized as well.

I am displaying these images inside div with `class=imagewrap` and the images have class `images` with them.

**My overall aim**

1. To display multiple images on each widget with there aspect ratio maintained(as far as possible).Atleast they should look proper.
2. Images should be within that div only
3. To increase/decrease the size of image when the widget is resized.

**What I have achieved/tried so far**

I am able to place the image in divs (but I have seen that some images do not lie within the div but come out of it) and then placing those div on the widget. I am not sure the approach which I have used for that is proper or not.

I have declared class imagewrap which forms a div for the images.It is as follows:

```
.imagewrap {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative; 

  min-height: 50px;
  min-width:  50px;
/*
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width:100px;
*/
  width: 25%;

  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Each image is having a class `images` which is a follows

```
.images {
  position: absolute;
  /*height: 100%;   commented to keep the aspect ratio when the widget is resized*/
  width: 100% ;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

HTML Code where the images are placed

```
<div class="imagewrap"><img class="images" src='+ images[j] +' title="' + titles[j]+ '"><input type="button" class="removediv" value="X" /></div></div>
```

**The problem I am facing**

When I resize the widget the images tend to overlap each other.I am not getting how to fix it.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgcq3pq4/)
In fiddle as you resize/stretch the widget.The images start to overlap

If anyone feel that class which I declared are wrong in itself considering the output that I want then please change them as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in order to keep images inside containers you have to provide **max-width: 100%** and **max-height:100%** to images. After that you can provide height and width to class **imagewrap**.

Try this:

```
.imagewrap {
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;

  max-height: 50px;
  max-width:  50px;

  width: 25%;

  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}


.images {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Should container height width be also in percentage ?

Comment: No, imagewrap can have max-height and max-width in px, but images should have max-height and max-width as 100%

Comment: Is there anyway by which I can define the minimum image size(I mean the div size such that the images wont be too small)

Comment: I changed the `max-height` and  `max-width` to 100px and it works fine when I enlarge the image.But by default they are to small

Comment: min-width and min-height can also be added, it is working when i try it. Let me know

Comment: I was trying with fixing the div height and width to `80px`.But is it possible that when I resize the widget the box will increase

Comment: I mean dynamically increase both height and width with base as 80px

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is the fix, just change some properties in .images class.

```
.images {
/* position: absolute; */
/*height: 100%; */
width: 100% ;
/* top: 0; */
/* left: 0; */
object-fit: contain;
}
```